# Check if div content starts with newlines and remove them

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to check if content of a div starts with a newline? If it does then remove all leading newlines until the first character that is not a newline. I have tried,

```
if ($('#div').text().substring(0, 1) == '\n'){
    $('#div').text($('#div').text().replace("\n",""));
}
```

The above example checks if the div content starts with 1 newline. Of course, you already see the restriction here. Div could start with multiple new lines. Also I don't want to remove new lines that may appear after the first proper character.

```
     <- must be removed
     <- must be removed
      .
      .
      .
      n
a
a
a
     <- must not be removed
a
a
```

Another case could be where the div starts without a new line, in which case nothing should be removed.

***Edit:** Also the content of the div could be huge so looping probably isn't an elegant solution.*

Comment: `replace` only works on the first instance of the target string. Try `.split('\n').join('')` (this would also snip the new lines in the middle though)

Comment: @tewathia Yea I don't want to strip any other newlines or spaces. Just the leading (if there are) new lines

Comment: `.split('\n').filter(function(e, i){return e!=""}).join('\n')` This is what you want

Comment: not a good idea, that removes every newline in the div. Have you ever heard of so called loops?!

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this? I am asking because the browser ignores leading white space characters anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/YCLLP/.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, not in my case because I have set `white-space: pre-wrap` to keep everything intact. And so just want to remove leading empty lines.

Comment: @user1768337 that's what the the `<pre>` tag is for. Use it for preformatted text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression replacement:

```
$('#div').text(function(i, orig) {
    return orig.replace(/^\n+/, '');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4hC4p/11/)

Comment: I can't seem to make this work. It's returning me value without remove the leading newlines.

Comment: Works for me, see the fiddle.

Comment: Ah I get what you mean. It does remove the first newline. However on consecutive newlines this fails?

Comment: I've updated my fiddle to have 4 newlines, it removes them all. See the new link above.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any spaces between the newlines.

Comment: Oops, that does it. Thanks for the help. This works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

With due respect to **Barmar**'s answer if you need **any whitespace character(newline included)** before the actual content of the div to be removed you can use this-

```
$('#div').text(function(i, orig) {
    updated = orig.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    return updated;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`, then `filter` out the empty elements of the array formed and then rejoin them with `join`

```
$('#div').text($('#div').text().split('\n').filter(function (e) {
    return e != ""
}).join('\n'));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/C7Aeu/)

Admittedly, this would not work precisely as you want. If there are consecutive `\n`s(somewhere in the middle of your content), it would club them into a single newline.

Comment: Sorry, left out a `)`. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but still not working. I moved the `)` so that join is implemented after the `text(..)`. But now it's removing all white spaces.

Comment: @user1768337 No, no, it must be before the `text` is closed. See the code and demo now

Comment: I tried using your solution to new lines and this is what I got. http://jsfiddle.net/vdxLD/

Comment: Ah. This is because the newlines aren't separated by identical (empty "") strings. It's considering `"       "`(notice the space in between) to be not empty. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/vdxLD/1/). Feels like a very hack-y way of doing it though, I'd suggest you go with the RegEx solution

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Barmar's solution seems to work now. :D